# Encrypting fields in a huge SQL DB

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a huge SQL 2008 DB with ~300 million rows. some of the tables have columns with an encrypted value.
The DB was gradually build using an application (.net 4). 
We are considering to move to some hardware (USB token) like encryption but that mean we will have to change the encrypted values in the DB.
We've written a small app that decrypts with the old key and then encrypt with the token but it takes days for it to run since I have to SELECT the row and UPDATE one at a time by ID. the db is indexed but still...

The Encrypt(string) method is a functionality provided by the USB token and I can access it via .net
I'm looking for a more direct way to use that functionality. maybe access it through SQL or something.

Comment: No accepted answers and one upvote for 8 previous questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131102.aspx) stored procedure to access the USB dongle on the server. You'd need [UNSAFE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx) access of course

This will reduce network overhead because you don't want to do a single 300 million row update. You'd still need it [RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) or batched: I'd suggest RBAR to keep it simple.

Comment: My other option was using the .net application but with bulk insert. the application will run directly on the server so network is not an issue.
Which one will be best?